# export the all ES indexes and documents from remote server(linux) to local server(windows)

Tags: elasticsearch

How to export the all documents (300 000 docs) from remote elastic server that is deployed in Linux server and import those documents to local server that is deployed in windows.I want to replicate the same environment in local server that exists in remote server.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using [Logstash](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/index.html) to achieve this, using the configuration below. Make sure to replace the source and target hosts, as well as the index and type names to match your local environment.

**File: copy.conf**

```
input {
  elasticsearch {
   hosts => "linux_host:9200"       <---- your remote Linux host
   index => "index_to_copy"
  }
}
filter {
 mutate {
  remove_field => [ "@version", "@timestamp" ]
 }
}
output {
 elasticsearch {
   host => "localhost"       <--- your local Windows host
   port => 9200
   protocol => "http"
   manage_template => false
   index => "index_to_copy"
 }
}
```

And then you can simply launch it with

```
bin/logstash -f copy.conf
```

Another possibility is to use the [snapshot & restore](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-snapshots.html) feature.